# "Date field is required" error when saving entries

Tags: expresso-store, php, error, php.ini

I'm using Store to manage products with lots of modifiers. At some point, a product will reach a number of modifiers where it starts producing a "Date field is required" error every time I try to save the entry in the Publish Page. There is, of course, a value in the Date field, but somehow it seems to not be making it to the server properly. How can I troubleshoot/fix this? Is it possible to have "too many" modifiers on a product?

Answer (score 4):

Turns out, this has nothing to do with Store at all. Found my answer on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977497/php-and-too-many-input-fields):

> Since PHP 5.3.9 there's a new configuration setting called
>   "[max_input_vars](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars)" which limits the number of input variables. The
>   default setting is 1000. Also check if [Suhosin](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/) is installed, because
>   there's also a [similar setting](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.post.max_vars).

Comment: Yeah, suhosin can be a pain, especially if you have lots of matrix/grid fields on your publish page it's quite easy to exceed the 1000 input var limit. Just bump it up to 5000 or something.